# I lied about a dream and I want to do tauba

Tags: dua, forgiveness

I lied about having a dream about someone. I told them I had a dream about them. I wanted to be in touch with them and made it up. I thought it was a good way to start a conversation for them. Something they will be interested in as we are not friends. I somehow thought by me telling this person a good dream, they will be happy and maybe like me.
 The dream I made up was a good dream islamicly with a good meaning I believed. They were happy. But I felt guilty right after. For giving false happiness.
 I'm sorry and felt bad. I found out just now that telling a false dream is one of the biggest sins. I will never do this again. I did not know.

Can someone please tell me the dua for repentance for telling a false dream. I want to repent but don't know exactly what to read or do for telling a false dream.

JhazakAllah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allah is The GOD of hearts, meaning that what matters is what's in your heart. If you are deeply and truly sorry, and have the intention of repenting and not doing it again, pray 2 rakaas and make some dua and Allah (subhanahu w taalah) will know your intention and inshallah he will forgive you.

As for duas (in general), although there are some common duas said by the Prophet (peace be upon him) or the sahabas, communication between a person and Allah is not a rigid or systematic process. You make whatever dua you find suitable, and being creative and emotional about your duas is encouraged. 

An example of creativity in dua, a well known dua made by older scholars and sahabas is asking Allah(subhanahu w taalah):
`Ya Allah, my mother would have mercy on me if I made a mistake and repented. Would you not have mercy on me and you are the "most merciful", "most compassionate"` 
PS: Excuse my poor translation of the dua, for I know it in Arabic.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!. I will do as suggested. If you don't mind can you please copy and paste r share the link for the dua in Arabic?. The one you translated in English.  Thank you again.

Comment: I couldn't find it because I don't remember exactly who said it, but I've heard it many times in jumaa prayer or read it in books. If you can read arabic, here's a good dua:<br>
`يا ربي، انّ أمّي لترحمني ان نسيت أو أخطأت، أفلا ترحمني وأنت الرحمن الرحيم. أفلا ترحمني يا من بيده خزائن الرحمة كلها. أفلا ترحمني يا من وسعت رحمته كل شيء. سبحانك لا اله الا أنت سبحانك اني كنت من الظالمين. إلّا ترحمني وتغفر لي لأكوننّ من الخاسرين. أنت ربي ومولاي، وأنا  العبد الفقير اليك `.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't find it, but be creative in your dua, and use [this](https://khutabaa.com/khutabaa-section/corncr-speeches/175554) as a reference to make your own dua